# Cortex-M0+ check if running under debugger control

Tags: cortex-m0+

I would like to check from my firmware if the MCU is running under debugger control. The MCU is a Cortex-M0+ KE06Z128.

On M4 I used to check a bit in DHCSR. Even though this [register exists in M0+](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0484b/BABJHEIG.html), it seems to not be available to the firmware (I can't find it anywhere in device headers).

Is there a way to check if an M0+ is running under debugger control (apart from setting some variable by the debugger)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plainly, you can't by reading register. You just can't access those.

However, there are some other workarounds:
  - See if semihosting is online `BKPT 0xAB`. But it throws an hardfault when its 
not...
  - Have the debug initialisation script write a bit somewhere in memory.
  - Read the SWD pin states, if the hardware supports that.